# When loading a generated textfile to a MySQL table a strange characters is inserted

Tags: mysql, formatting, special-characters

I'm loading a generated textfile to my MySQL to add a row to a table.
After the insert a strange character appears infront of the value in the first column.

When copied and pasted into Word with special characters activated the character looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1udMZ.jpg

The character behaves like a "hidden whitespace".

The row in the table looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZZLc.jpg

You can't see the character in the row but its infront off "BORD". Because of this I can't do a SELECT statement on that row.

The code to insert the file looks like this:

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\tfs\Eline\Release\414A\ElineWS\ArtData\TempTable.txt'

The text in the file looks like this:

BORD        181002  300925                  False   3   False

Between each column there is a \t

Comment: Did you look at the text file with a Hex Editor

Comment: Erase everything at the top of your file until ..ORD

Comment: With the help of the Hex Editor I found out it was the BOM character which interfered. Thank you.